# How to remove an object from array based on value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object, I want to remove entire object from the array whose value is 1, I am using filter but not working. Here is the code:

```js
var arraydata = [
  {"name":"name1","value":1},
  {"name":"name2","value":2},
  {"name":"name3","value":3}
];

arraydata.filter(i=>i.value !== 1);
console.log(arraydata);
```

Comment: arraydata = arraydata.filter(...)

Comment: Filter returns a new array and doesn’t alter the original.

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) _The `filter()` method creates a **new array** with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.filter` return a new array rather than mutating the current one. So you should reassign `arraydata`

```js
var arraydata = [{
  "name": "name1",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "name": "name2",
  "value": 2
}, {
  "name": "name3",
  "value": 3
}];

arraydata = arraydata.filter(i => i.value !== 1);
console.log(arraydata);
```

Comment: is it possible using splice

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it:

```js
let arraydata = [{"name":"name1","value":1},{"name":"name2","value":2},{"name":"name3","value":3}];
const after = arraydata.filter(x=>x.value !== 1);
console.log('before',arraydata,'after',after);
arraydata = after;
```

note: it is better not to use i for the item in the filter (it is not an error, but may cause confusion when you want to filter by content and by index)